# Deleting a created file at every iteration

Tags: powershell

```
$getFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $readDir -File -Include "*.doc","*.docx","*.xlsx"-Recurse | %{


    if(($_ -match "\.doc$") -or ($_ -match "\.docx$")){
        $Doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.fullname)
        $nameDoc = $fileSaveLoc + $_.Name.Replace(".docx",".txt").replace(".doc",".txt")
        $Doc.saveas([ref] $nameDoc, [ref] 5)
        $Doc.close()

        if((Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\").length -ne 0){
            $locations = (Get-Item "I:\temp\"), (Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\" -Directory -recurse) | % {
            Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName | Select-String -List -Pattern '^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$' | 
            % Path
            }

            if($locations -ne $null){
                $locations | out-file "I:\temp\SSN_FILES.txt"
                #Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\" -exclude "fullpath.txt","SSN_FILES.txt" | remove-item
            }else{
                Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\" -exclude "fullpath.txt","SSN_FILES.txt" | remove-item
            }   
        }
    }
    elseif($_ -match "\.xlsx$"){ 
        $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
        $csvFilePath = "I:\temp\" + $_.Name.Replace(".xlsx",".csv") 
        #$csvFilePath = $_.FullName -replace "\.xlsx$", ".csv"
        $workbook.SaveAs($csvFilePath, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSV)
        $workbook.Close()

        if((Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\").length -ne 0){
            $locations = (Get-Item "I:\temp\"), (Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\" -Directory -recurse) | % {
            Get-ChildItem -File $_.FullName | Select-String -List -Pattern '^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$' | 
            % Path
            }

            if($locations -ne $null){
                $locations | out-file "I:\temp\SSN_FILES.txt"
                #Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\" -exclude "fullpath.txt","SSN_FILES.txt" | remove-item
            }else{
                Get-ChildItem "I:\temp\" -exclude "fullpath.txt","SSN_FILES.txt" | remove-item
            }   

        }
    }
}
```

So this basically says:

- check for a file matching doc/docx/xlsx
- convert them into a file that can be parsed through
- parse through each file at every iteration and compare it to a regex
- if the regex is not null, then output it to a file with the file path
- otherwise, delete it and anything else that was created except for two files
- restart the process at the next file

Now the problem I am encountering is that the files aren't being deleted. I can't get them to be removed when they are created, when I know they don't match the regex. Setting `($locations -eq $true)` doesn't solve that issue because it never goes into the first conditional statement.

The folder should contain only the two files that were created and possibly the ones that match the regex.

Comment: Are there any error messages? Try to use -force by the remove-item cmdlet

Comment: I was able to get it to work by some weird method. It shouldn't work, but it does. It is the weirdest thing ever. There is no explanation for it, i think it is just how it interacts with the word/excel applications. Literally, it shouldn't work the way I have it. :\ I don't want to touch the code anymore because I'm afraid if I add something it will muck it up somehow and I'll never be able to go back. There weren't any error messages. the only way I could debug was by adding write outs to see where it jumped to and how it acted when it jumped.